# how to iterate over aws cli result using bash for loop ? [describe-images]

Tags: bash, loops, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

Goal: find specific AMI's and copy them to another AWS region.

using `describe-images` and its filter i get a list of ImageId and Name,

```
AMI_LIST=$(aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*one*,*two*,*three*,*four*" \
"Name=state,Values=available" "Name=tag:Name,Values=${CUSTOMER_NAME}*" \
--query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,NAME:Name}' --output text)
```

```
echo $AMI_LIST
```

result:

```
ami-036ba4ef9fa1d148d big394_one_1 ami-06d13684f11138f1f big394_two_3 ami-0706803a11e21946d big394_two_1 ami-094043f896db39243 big394_two_2 ami-0c11ff60c981c2273 big394_three_1 ami-0d0b30fcc69f30af8 big394_four_1
```

then i want to copy the images to another AWS region using a loop:

```
for ami in $AMI_LIST; do
aws ec2 copy-image --source-image-id ${ami[0]} --source-region us-east-1 --region us-west-2 --name ${ami[2]}
done
```

ofc it does not work because `${ami[0]}` and `${ami[1]}` has no meaning, but they represent what i would like to achieve.

i did try to play with converting the list to array but without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you expected :

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*one*,*two*,*three*,*four*" \
"Name=state,Values=available" "Name=tag:Name,Values=${CUSTOMER_NAME}*" \
--query 'Images[*].{ID:ImageId,NAME:Name}' --output text \
| while read ami name; do
    aws ec2 copy-image --source-image-id $ami --source-region us-east-1\
                       --region us-west-2 --name $name
done
```

Comment: That was easy :-)  THANK YOU.